# Large font in Pantheon greeter

Tags: release-loki, greeter, pantheon, fonts, accessibility

Due to my relatively poor vision, I prefer to have large icons and form fields in all of my working environments. I don't need to take it as far as installing Vinux though.

In Manjaro and other OSes, I can customise the login manager. 
I have just installed elementary OS. While I do understand the desig philosophy of minimal customisability, I would nevertheless like to have large fonts and form field height for the pantheon-greeter screen? How can I achieve this and make it a bit more accessible?

Answer (score 1):

edit /etc/lightdm/pantheon-greeter.conf 
for example, I'm using Roboto font for the login screen

```
    [greeter]
    #activate-numlock=true
    #default-wallpaper=/usr/share/backgrounds/elementaryos-default
    #high-contrast=false
    #onscreen-keyboard=false
    #screensaver-timeout=60
    font-name=Roboto 11
```

Comment: Be sure to open `/etc/lightdm/pantheon-greeter.conf` in a plain-text text-editor, such as Scratch which comes with EOS, or `nano` / `vim` on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

You can tweak the text size in System Settings -> Universal Access -> Display -> Reading. 
[image]

Comment: This does not work for the login manager